# Storing 'struct' data to binary file

Tags: python, header-files, binaryfiles

I need to store a binary file with a 12 byte header composed of 4 fields. They are namely: sSamples (4-bytes integer), sSampPeriod (4-bytes integer), sSampSize (2-bytes integer), and finally sParmKind (2-bytes integer).
I'm using 'struct' to my variables to the desired fields. Now that I have them defined separately, how could I merge them all to store the '12 bytes header'?

```
sSamples        = struct.pack('i', nSamples) # 4-bytes integer
sSampPeriod     = struct.pack('i', nSampPeriod) # 4-bytes integer
sSampSize       = struct.pack('H', nSampSize) # 2-bytes integer / unsigned short
sParmKind       = struct.pack('H', 9) # 2-bytes integer / unsigned short
```

In addition, I've a `npVect` float array of dimensionality D (`numpy.ndarray` - float32). How could I store this vector in the same binary file, but after the header?

Comment: Note that you can pack multiple values at once: struct.pack('Hi', foo, bar).  Also, you ought to put a '>' or '<' before the format string, so it'll pack and unpack properly on systems with different endianness.

Answer (score 2):

As Cody Brocious wrote, you can pack your entire header at once:

```
header = struct.pack('<iiHH', nSamples, nSampPeriod, nSampSize, nParmKind)
```

He also mentioned endianness, which is important if you want to pack your data so as to reliably unpack it on machines with different architectures. The `<` at the beginning of my format string specifies "pack this data using a little-endian convention".

As for the array, you'll have to pack its length in order to determine how many values to unpack when you read it again. Doing it all in one call:

```
flattened = npVect.ravel()  # get a 1-D array of numbers
arrSize = len(flattened)
# pack header, count of numbers, and numbers, all in one call
packed = struct.pack('<iiHHi%df' % arrSize,
    nSamples, nSampPeriod, nSampSize, nParmKind, arrSize, *flattened)
```

Depending on how big your array is likely to be, you could end up with a huge string representing the entire contents of your binary file, and you might want to look into alternatives to `struct` which don't require you to have the entire file in memory.

Unpacking:

```
fmt = '<iiHHi'
nSamples, nSampPeriod, nSampSize, nParmKind, arrSize = struct.unpack(fmt, packed)
# Use unpack_from to start reading after the packed header and count
flattened = struct.unpack_from('<%df' % arrSize, packed, struct.calcsize(fmt))
npVect = np.ndarray(flattened, dtype='float32').reshape(# your dimensions go here
    )
```

**EDIT**: Oops, the array format isn't quite as simple as that :) The general idea holds, though: flatten your array into a list of numbers using any method you like, pack the number of values, then pack each value. On the other side, read the array as a flat list, then impose whatever structure you need on it.

**EDIT**: Changed format strings to use repeat specifiers, rather than string multiplication. Thanks to John Machin for pointing it out.

**EDIT**: Added `numpy` code to flatten the array before packing and reconstruct it after unpacking.

Comment: `'<iiHHi%df' % arrSize` is a better idea than `'<iiHHi' + 'f' * arrSize'`, especially if the array is large.

Comment: +1 Good point, had forgotten you could put numbers in there. If the array is *really* large though, you're still going to be passing many parameters to `pack`, thanks to tuple-unpacking the array, and you'll have a huge string returned from it. Both of which point to finding alternatives to `struct` if performance suffers enough.

Comment: Hi guys, I was following the advice of: arrSize = len(arr)
packed = struct.pack('<iiHHi%df' % arrSize,
    nSamples, nSampPeriod, nSampSize, nParmKind, arrSize, *arr)
However, following error is shown:
struct.error: pack requires exactly 14005 arguments
Which is the type of "arr"?

Comment: The type of my array is np.ndarray of float. I need to convert from float to a 4 byte array. I didn't completely understand the suggestion of packing the number of values and then pack each value.Is this the case when instead of having a np.narray, we've a normal python list,right? So,if it's a python list,I'll have to iterate the vector & then call: myElem = struct.pack('f', myFlattedArr[i]) binfile.write(myElem)? Is that what you guys were talking about? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you'll have to convert your ndarray into a 1-dimensional structure like a list or tuple. **But** you *don't* have to iterate the vector; that's what the `%d` in the format string and `*arr` are for. If `arr` is a list of 17 floats, then `struct.pack('<%df' % len(arr), *arr)` packs all `n` of them in one call: the string passed to `pack` is the same as if you'd passed `'<17f'` (because it's formatted using the `%` operator) and tells `pack` to expect 17 floats. The `*` in `*arr` effectively passes each float as a separate argument, rather than passing (the list) `arr` as one argument.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include `numpy` code for flattening the array before packing and reconstructing it after unpacking.

Answer (score 1):

`struct.pack` returns a string, so you can combine the fields simply by string concatenation:

```
header = sSamples + sSampPeriod + sSampSize + sParmKind
assert len( header ) == 12
```

Comment: Hi jhcl, thanks for the advice! To store the header to the binary file, it's sth. like:
    binfile = open('myfile.dat', 'wb')
    binfile.write(header)

and then, how could I attach my 'npVect' variable to 'binfile'?

Comment: That is exactly right for writing the value to the file.  I'm not familiar with numpy, so I'll let someone else comment on that.